# How to call inherited function in react child component

Tags: reactjs, inheritance

I have 2 components. One extendind another like this

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component { 
   myCustomFunction = () => { 
    .. 
    this.setState({
       myVar: 'pippo'
    }); 
   }
}  

export default class Child extends Parent { 
  myCustomFunction = () => { 
    //I want to call here my parent myCustomFunction 
    .. 
    this.setState({
       myVar: 'pluto',
       otherVar: 'paperino'
    }); 
   }

   render (){
     return 
        <button onClick={this.myCustomFunction } />
    }
}
```

When someone click on button in Child I want to run the Parent function and then do some other stuff on the state.

How can I achieve this without coping the Parent in the Child?

Comment: Using callbacks. Check for callbacks concept in react

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's lots of approaches but I think you're looking for how to inherit the Parent's function like you would traditionally in any class inheritance model.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  parentFunc() {
    console.log(`Parent`);
  }
}


class Child extends Parent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  childFunc() {
    console.log(`Child`);
    super.parentFunc();
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.childFunc}>Click me</button>;
  }
}
```

CodeSandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/k3n1664323

MDN docs on super() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

p.s. You cannot call `super` in the context of an arrow function, you will need to use a regular function expression or take a different approach, potentially like the other answer suggested.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions